# Error running template Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):

Tags: json, freemarker

When tried reading a hash using Freemarker, it is reading the string variable having same name as that of hash prior to that, even though the string variable exists at different sub-level.

The JSON file is in below format.

```
"Record": {
    "@id": "Vehicle#1234#",
    "Color": {
        "@id": "MasterCode#5678#",
        "Code": "RED",
        "CodeClass": "",
        "CreatedBy": "system",
        "CreatedOn": "2015-09-10T00:00:00.0",
        "CustomFields": {            
        },
        "DisplayOrder": "999",
        "Name": "RED",
        "NibrsType": "",
        "Recnum": "5678",
        "Type": "XXXX"
    },
    "Type": {
        "@id": "MasterCode#9012#",
        "Code": "MPVH",
        "CodeClass": "",
        "CreatedBy": "system",
        "CreatedOn": "2015-09-10T00:00:00.0",
        "CustomFields": {
                    },
        "DisplayOrder": "999",
        "Name": "SUV TYPE VEHICLE",
        "NibrsType": "",
        "Recnum": "9012",
        "Type": "YYYY"
    }
}
```

when I tried reading *payload.Record.Type* hash, freemarker is reading the string under *payload.Record.Color.Type* and gives following error.

> Error running template Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):

Looking for some suggestions to get rid of this.

Comment: It's very unlikely that such bug exists. Could you double check your data-model (and everything...)?

Comment: I checked this and come across this issue in so many occurrences. Currently we are using  FreeMarker 2.3.25-incubating. Whenever I tried reading the variables under Type hash freemarker thrown this error as it is referring the variable with same name prior to that.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal but complete (i.e., it actually runs and fails) example to reproduce this behavior? How the JSON was exposed to the template (i.e., object wrapping) is of particular interest.

Comment: I need to check with my team, whether I can share this info or not. Meanwhile can you try reproducing this. Here is the template that has been used to read the Json file given above.

Comment: {
 <#if payload.Record?has_content>
 <#assign rec = payload.Record>
 <#if (rec.Color.Recnum)!?length gt 0>
 "Color" : {
  "Code": "${rec.Color.Code}?json_string",
  "Type": "${rec.Color.Type}?json_string"
 },
 </#if>
 <#if (rec.Type.Recnum)!?length gt 0>
 "BodyType" : {
  "Code": "${rec.Type.Code}?json_string",
  "Type": "${rec.Type.Type}?json_string"
 }
 </#if> 
 </#if>
}

Comment: How was that JSON file read/parsed? With other words, what do you pass to Template.process as data-model? (The template itself won't help, as things like `payload.Record.Type` work fine in general.) BTW, you have `?json_string`-s outside the `${}`-s, which can't be right, though it doesn't cause FreeMarker error.

Comment: The flower brackets was a typo. It should be ()

Comment: Regarding parsing of JSON file, if Json node is of type OBJECT, we are parsing it as a HashMap. In the above example JSON file, if Type hash is located prior to Color hash there is no issue. However we cannot restrict on the order of JSON nodes. In my observation, if a node of same name exists two places, always the first node with the given name (eventhough it is at different sub-level) got read and the error is thrown.

Comment: As `Color.Type` is on one lever deeper, it shouldn't cause any such ordering dependency with the stock `ObjectWrapper`-s of FreeMarker. It's as if you have some custom code there that does deep searching for `Type`. Can you check what's your `object_wrapper` configuration setting (`Configuration.getObjectWrapper()`)? Also, what's the exact `TemplateModel` class of `payload.Record` (Try to do something illegal with it, like `payload.Record + 1`, and the error message should tell the class, at least in not too old FreeMarker versions)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. We figured our that there exists an issue with JSON parsing and the issue got resolved after fixing the same at our end.